Is a Function Block passed to another Function Block passed by value or reference, in CODESYS?
In CODESYS, it seems to be possible to pass a function block instance to another function block instance's VAR_INPUT variable. Is the first function block instance passed as value or as reference?
I'm unable to find any documenation on it. A link to official documentation where this is explained would be useful.

The docs for VAR_INPUT clearly state:

When called, only the value is passed (pass-by-value).

So a copy is made on every call.
If you wish to pass by reference, you have several options:

Define the variable as a POINTER TO the function block and pass the pointer to the FB to be passed using the ADR() function.

Define the variable as a REFERENCE TO the function block and pass the reference to the FB to be passed. Note: If you wish to store a reference to an object, you should use the REF= assignment, for example refToA: REFERENCE TO SOMETHING REF= A;

Define the variable inside the VAR_IN_OUT block, which is really just sugarcode for VAR_INPUT with REFERENCE TO.

The prefered way for passing function blocks as reference is to use the OOP approach and use interfaces, which according to the docs, CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of an interface as references.


Unless the function block that is being passed is abstract, it would probably be better to define an interface with the desired functionality and pass that for better future flexibility.

A VAR_INPUT is passed by value, unless the input is declared as a REFERENCE TO (or a POINTER TO, which is technically a value but that value is an "address" which can be dereferenced), in which case it is passed by reference.
Unless I am mistaken, the same applies to all data types, except for interfaces, which act as references at all times.
